# How to do integration tests with mocked service

Tags: spring, testing, mocking, mockito, integration-testing

I'm working at a small parking service REST API.
For example I have endpoint:

```java
@RequestMapping("/departure")
public ResponseEntity<String> departure(@RequestBody CarAtGateModel carAtGateModel) throws Exception {
    return parkingService.carDeparture(carAtGateModel.getCarEntity().getIdCar());
}
```

method parkingService.carDeparture looks like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> carDeparture(String carID) throws UnidentifiedCarException {
    CarAndParkingIDsEntity carAndParkingIDsEntity = carAndParkingIDsRepository.findByIdCar(carID);

    if (carAndParkingIDsEntity == null) {
        throw new UnidentifiedCarException();
    } else {
        carAndParkingIDsEntity.setIdParking("-1");
        carAndParkingIDsRepository.flush();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Gate up", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And the problem is when I'm trying to do some integration tests. Unit tests for parking service pass correctly but I don't know exactly what should I do for integration tests.
I was thinking about something like. Mock carAtGateModel (it's carId and ParkingId) and send it to the endpoint and then mock parkingservice because I'm using it inside and I don't want to change data in the database.

```
when(parkingService.carDeparture(anyString())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("Gate up", 
HttpStatus.OK));    
HttpEntity<CarAtGateModel> request = new HttpEntity<>(carAtGateModel);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/departure", request, 
String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `@WebMvcTest` instead to have a slice test (sort of integration test that focuses on a single application layer).

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)
public class YourControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ParkingService parkingService;

    // Your test cases here
}
```

You would use `mockMvc` to perform an actual call to the REST endpoint with an actual `CarAtGateModel` object as JSON in the request body. You would also mock the behaviour of your `ParkingService`, thus focusing the test on your `Controller`.